# How to manually escape a character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

I'm not sure how to phrase this correctly. Basically, I want to take a string composed of a backslash an an "escapable" character and convert it to the actual escaped form:

```
console.log(magicStringFunction('\\n') === '\n') // true
```

What I'm trying to do is effectively the inverse of `String.raw`:

```
console.log(String.raw`\n` === '\\n') // true
```

I am aware that I can technically do this with `eval`:

```
console.log(eval('"\\n"')); // \n
```

However, I generally like to avoid using eval. Is there a way to do this with native code?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer! Just goes to show that I need to do a bit more investigating before asking a question...

You can use `JSON.parse`, which is similar to `eval` in this case, but less dangerous and (I believe) faster.

```
console.log(JSON.parse('"\\n"') === '\n') // true
```

Comment: Oh, I thought that you were talking about developing a syntax analysis for Javascript, as in automata theory and compiler design.

Comment: Close, but your solution will break when a double quote `"` is passed in.

Comment: it seems it also won't work when you try to parse `"\\v"`, which I want it to work for. I want this to work for "r", "n", "t", "v", "f", and "b". For now, I'm settling for `char === 'v' ? '\v' : JSON.parse('"\\' + char + '"')`

Comment: @jchitel Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of your proposed solution:

```
function magicStringFunction(w){
    return JSON.parse('"' + w + '"');
}
```

But it will fail when this happens:

```
magicStringFunction('"\\n"');     // whoops
```

---

A version that prevents this from happening:

```
function magicStringFunction(w){
    return w.replace(/\\./g, function(match){
        return JSON.parse('"' + match + '"');
    });
}
```

Might not be exactly very efficient but it works.

---

Or if you are not a big fan of JSON.parse for efficiency, you can do this instead:

```
function magicStringFunction(w){
    // Defined by Table 34 under section 11.8.4.3
    // ' " \ b f n r t v
    var escCharMap = {
        "\\'": "'",
        "\\\"": "\"",
        "\\\\": "\\",
        "\\b": "\b",
        "\\f": "\f",
        "\\n": "\n",
        "\\r": "\r",
        "\\t": "\t",
        "\\v": "\v"
    };

    return w.replace(/\\./g, function(match){
        if(escCharMap.hasOwnProperty(match)) return escCharMap[match];
        else                                 return match.substr(1, 1);
    });
}
```

Ref: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-SingleEscapeCharacter